# what does this devise config do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to restrict devise to json requests on an api with this from the internet. What does it do?

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb

config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = ["*/", :html, :json]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From devise documentation,

config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

```
If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
```

config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]

```
==> Navigation configuration
   Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
   :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
   access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.

   If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
   should add them to the navigational formats lists.

   The :"*/*" and "*/*" formats below is required to match Internet
   Explorer requests.
```